# animating xml elements in java code in dps (android studio)

Tags: android, xml

I'm using android studio to design a game.
I used the 'dp' unit in my 'xml' file for defining my elements. 
In java code, I want to move those elements by function animate() like image_button_red1.animate().xBy(first value).yBy(second value);
this function only takes float value, But the animation is different in each device.
I want to use the 'dp' unit to solve this problem.
Is there a function that takes another unit like 'dp'?

Comment: why don't you use translation property like layoutname.setTranslationX(view, 50f); or setTranslationY(view, 50f);

Comment: Thanks. I've used this function. It only takes 1 argument and it's float like xby function. And it didn't solve the problem. The problem is that the float value is different in each device.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer.
I designed my layout in pixels and when I used, for example, animate().xby(10.0f), the translation was right in each device. The equation between the pixel and dp is: px = dp * (dpi / 160);
Then I used dp instead of px and used the function Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density to get the density of each screen which is running the code.
So I used a float variable instead of 10.0f which this value calculated from the noted equation. My object size was 360 dp, and the equation changed to px = 2.25*dpi.
And in my case, I used a variable like this:
float House_size = 2.25f * 14.44f * Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
then I used animate().xby(House_size);
And now the result works properly on every single device.